# Custom onChange event

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

Is there a recommended approach for firing custom events based on change to a value? I have a variable, let's call it `status`, that comes from an external API and will change from `queued` -> `in progress` -> `complete`.

I want to observe the change in that variable and fire events appropriately. Right now how it works is like this: I am polling for the status every 2 seconds, and the server response is something like below:

```
<status> @ <every X seconds of polling>
queued @ 0s
queued @ 2s
queued @ 4s
in progress @ 6s
in progress @ 8s
in progress @ 10s
in progress @ 12s
in progress @ 14s
in progress @ 16s
complete @ 18s
complete @ 20s
complete @ 22s
complete @ 24 s
```

I am changing some DOM elements based on this status. I want to minimize the DOM manipulation from 12 times to something like 3. The naive approach to handle this seems to be doable by maintaining a previous status and a current status variable, but I want to know if this is possible by using something like CustomEvent.

Comment: getters/setters or Proxy could help, depending on how the "status" is stored - i.e. how the variable is declared and used

Answer (score 0):

In the past something like this has been possible using the object's .watch() method.
Whenever the value of a property changed it triggered an event.
Unfortunately it's deprecated now.

Though it's a bit tricky we can kind of fake this behaviour using a **MutationObserver**.
The trick is, instead of storing your status changes in a variable **status**, store it in an invisible DIV and using the MutationObserver we can fire an event as soon as the DIV's innerHTML property changes.

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(handler),
  targetDiv = document.getElementById("dummy"),
  objConfig = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: false,
    characterData: false
  };

observer.observe(targetDiv, objConfig);

function handler() {
  console.log("something changed");
}

// the following part is just needed to simulate the change
setTimeout(changeIt, 1000);
function changeIt() {
  document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = "different";
}
```

```html
<div id="dummy" style="display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using a `Proxy` like so:

```
var jenkins_state = {
  current_status: null
};

var jenkins_state_proxy = new Proxy(jenkins_state, {
  set: function(target, key, value) {
    if (key !== 'current_status') return false;

    var currentValue = target[key];
    if (value !== currentValue) {
      // Do very expensive DOM modifications
      redraw_the_div();
      repaint_everything();
      console.log('status changed');
    }
    target[key] = value;
    return true;
  }
});

jenkins_state_proxy.current_status = "waiting"; // first run: fired
jenkins_state_proxy.current_status = "waiting"; // won't fire
jenkins_state_proxy.current_status = "waiting"; // won't fire
jenkins_state_proxy.current_status = "in queue"; // fired
jenkins_state_proxy.current_status = "in queue"; // won't fire
jenkins_state_proxy.current_status = "in queue"; // won't fire
jenkins_state_proxy.current_status = "in queue"; // won't fire
jenkins_state_proxy.current_status = "in progress"; // fired
jenkins_state_proxy.current_status = "in progress"; // won't fired
jenkins_state_proxy.current_status = "completed"; // fired
```

**Explanation:**

Basically I am only change tracking one thing here, and that is `current_status`. So I wrapped it in an object and created a wrapper object for it using a `Proxy`.  All my modifications happen through that proxy and they get intercepted by the `set` function. I am disallowing changes to the object (adding new keys) using the first `if`. And in the second `if` making sure the new value of `current_status` is handled appropriately.